# How can I set a value on redis terminal for a map?

Tags: java, redis

in my java code, I set the value of a hash as a map,

```
Map map<String, Long> map = new HashMap<>();
map.set("one",1L);
map.set("two",2L);
redisClient.hset("key", "field", map);
```

now I if I use redis hget to retrieve the value on redis terminal, I get

```
{"one":1, "two",2}
```

but if I want to set it on redis to  {"one":10, "two",20}

```
hset key field {"one":10, "two",20}
```

it seems ok, but my java program throws an exception with following statement

```
Map map<String, Long> map = redisClient.hget("key", "field");
```

the exception info:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map
```

How can I set a value on redis terminal for this map?

Comment: What does this line do - `Map map<String, Long> map = new HashMap();` ?

Comment: What the client for Redis are you using?

Comment: @Amitkumar new a HashMap